# React Native Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to navigate to List.js after I click the button in MainMenu.js file, but it always shows me this error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push')`

This is my App.js file

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { List } from './List';
import { MainMenu } from './MainMenu';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to stassrt working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <MainMenu></MainMenu>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And this is my MainMenu.js file (I have the button in this file):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ScreenContainer } from 'react-native-screens';
import { List } from './List';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';


export const MainMenu = ({navigation}) => (
    
    <View>
      <Text>Hello HOW ARE YsOU</Text>
      <Button title="Click" onPress={() => navigation.push("List")}></Button>
    </View>
    
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainMenu` component, you are expecting an object with a key `navigation` as props. You are not passing any props to the `MainMenu`, however, and so the props are undefined, but you are expecting an object. To fix this, change the component to:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ScreenContainer } from 'react-native-screens';
import { List } from './List';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';


export const MainMenu = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello HOW ARE YsOU</Text>
        <Button title="Click" onPress={() => navigation.push("List")}> 
        </Button>
      </View>
    ); 
};
```

We are using the hook, instead of props.

Comment: I wrote it like this but now it shows: " Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator? "

Comment: You didn't set up React Navigation correctly then. You have to include your App inside a screen navigator component for React Navigation to work. I suggest you look at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation, you need to create a stack navigator and wrap your app in it.

Comment: I tried to do it exactly as it was written there. It looks like this has no solution 

Comment: I reinstalled it and it solved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented the stack navigator, but I think your App.js file should look like this:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { List } from './List';
import { MainMenu } from './MainMenu';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator>
        <>
         <Stack.Screen name="Main Menu" component={MainMenu} />
         <Stack.Screen name="List" component={List} />
       </>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

And I think your MainMenu component should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ScreenContainer } from 'react-native-screens';
import { List } from './List';

export const MainMenu = ({navigation}) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Open up App.js to stassrt working on your app!</Text>
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
    <View>
     <Text>Hello HOW ARE YsOU</Text>
     <Button title="Click" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("List")</Button>      
    </View>
  </View>
```